# After a format, gulp in docker stops working normally

Tags: node.js, docker, gulp, debian

some time ago I created an image using a **Dockerfile** to mount a node container with **gulp**, the base used is **Debian** and everything worked correctly, but when I formatted and installed everything again it stopped working the way it was doing previously.

With this command the image is created, following the log that is kilometric, everything is installed normally.

```
sudo docker build -t app_node .
```

Once the image is created, I create a container with this other code:

```
docker run -it -v $PWD:/mi_app -p 8051:3001 -e PUID=1001 -e PGID=100 --name node_container app_node
```

The created volume is the web folder with the files that previously worked correctly. Once this command is executed, it enters the container and I can execute the **gulp** commands perfectly, everything works perfectly, but once I hit **exit**, the container stops, if I activate it again with **docker start** and put the gulp command it worked Ok, now it throws me an error:

**Command docker exec:**

```
docker exec -d node_container gulp babel_a && gulp minifi_a
```

**Error:**

```
Error: No such container: gulp
```

The web page to which I want to apply the gulp commands is located in /home/user/web

[image: folder site]

**gulpfile.js**

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
  concat = require('gulp-concat'),
  uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
  rename=require('gulp-rename'),
  clean = require('gulp-clean'),
  cssmin = require('gulp-cssmin'),
  replace = require('gulp-string-replace'),
  clean = require('gulp-clean'),
  babel = require('gulp-babel');




gulp.task('babel_a', async function () {


  gulp.src('www/js/*.js')

  .pipe(babel({
            presets: ["@babel/preset-env"]
        }))



  //.pipe(concat('cs.js'))
  .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('www/js/mov'));



  gulp.src(['www/blog/js/*.js',


   '!www/blog/js/jquery.cropit.js' // <== ignore file 
    ])

  .pipe(babel({
            presets: ["@babel/preset-env"]
        }))

  //.pipe(concat('cs.js'))
  .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('www/blog/js/mov'));




  gulp.src('www/blog/js/jquery.cropit.js'  
    )
  .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('www/blog/js/mov'));



});




gulp.task('minifi_a', async function () {


 gulp.src('www/js/mov/*.min.js')

  //.pipe(concat('cs.js'))
  .pipe(uglify())
  .pipe(rename({ prefix: '01-' }))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('www/js/'));

  gulp.src('www/blog/js/mov/*.min.js')
  //.pipe(concat('cs.js'))
  .pipe(uglify())
  .pipe(rename({ prefix: '01-' }))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('www/blog/js/'));




  gulp.src('www/blog/js/mov/*.min.js')

  .pipe(clean());

  gulp.src('www/js/mov/*.min.js')

  .pipe(clean());

//CSS

   gulp.src('www/css/*.css')
 

        .pipe(cssmin())
        .pipe(replace('}@media', '} @media'))
        .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
         .pipe(rename({ prefix: '01-' }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('www/css/'));


});
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "web",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "gulpfile.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.17.9",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.11",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-babel": "^8.0.0",
    "gulp-clean": "^0.4.0",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-cssmin": "^0.2.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-string-replace": "^1.1.2",
    "gulp-uglify": "^3.0.2"
  }
}
```

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM debian

RUN mkdir /mi_app
WORKDIR /mi_app
EXPOSE 3001

RUN apt-get update \
 && apt-get install -y sudo

RUN adduser --disabled-password --gecos '' docker
RUN adduser docker sudo
RUN echo '%sudo ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL' >> /etc/sudoers

USER docker

CMD /bin/bash

RUN cd /

RUN sudo apt-get install apt-utils && sudo apt install -y curl

RUN sudo curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | sudo -E bash - 

RUN sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install nodejs

RUN sudo npm install -g npm -y && node -v && npm -v

RUN sudo npm install gulp -g && gulp -v

RUN cd /mi_app

RUN sudo npm init -y

RUN sudo npm install gulp && gulp -v

RUN sudo npm install --save-dev gulp-concat gulp-uglify gulp-rename gulp-clean

RUN sudo npm install --save-dev gulp-cssmin gulp-string-replace gulp-clean

RUN sudo npm install --save-dev gulp-babel @babel/core @babel/preset-env
```

I have tried to find out why it gives that error, if everything is done and installed as it was before, why does it throw that error? Is something missing in the system? what am I missing?

Comment: Would it be easier to [install Node](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) directly on your host system?  Then you'd be able to just run `npx gulp` without any of the Docker-related infrastructure you show here – you'd literally be able to get rid of 2/3 of this question and you wouldn't have the problem you're encountering.

Comment: At the time I tried a node Docker image but I couldn't solve some problems, so I opted for a debian image and install modules. I'll try to test again with a node image, thank you very much!!